# What is the correct agreement here? Entirety or Entireties? (and why?)

Tags: grammar

I was writing an email earlier today and Grammarly (which has generally been very helpful) got on me about the word, "entireties" because it didn't agree with the subject. The sentence:

"I figured your intent was so that you wouldn't have to re-read everyone's papers in their entireties."

I think it's because the subject "everyone" is singular, and so it should be "entirety"? Someone help me clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Everyone's paper"s" Papers!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "everyone" really has multiple "papers", then your sentence is entirely correct. However, there are two reasons to choose "entirety" over "entireties".

First, the expression "in [its] entirety" commmonly appears as a set phrase, typically with the singular.

Second, we often prefer the singular form of an abstract noun even when it applies to multiple people (or things). For example:

> This battle will test the soldiers' loyalty.
> The speed of the runners will become apparent.

These sentences could have included "loyalties" and "speeds", but the singular forms are more common. Similarly, it is quite normal to say "entirety" instead of "entireties".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I still wanted to thank you. That made perfect sense and I appreciate your example!